# Add extra information to the zip

Tags: python

```
from itertools import groupby
#input
l = [['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'] ,
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'] ,
['Slever ', 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T. Slever']]
#script
l_clean = sorted(zip(zip(*l)[1], zip(*l)[4],))

l_final = [(k, zip(*v)[1]) for k,v in groupby(l_clean, key = lambda x:x[0])]

for k,v in l_final:

     print k,list(v)

#My output is:

Wei 9-11 ['AVB', 'BEDR']

klopt 42 ['AVB']

plein 92 ['AVB', 'BEDR']

tiellaan 42 ['AVB', 'DAS']
```

## Problem

My problem is that i can't seem to add the other data to the output the data i also want to have in the output is:

```
['Cautus  B.V.','1019123', '10', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'](not only for this entry but for all entry's)
```

I tryed everything changing/adding the key etc but it doesn't seem to work.
I know my english is vague so if i need to clarify some words or anything just say so.
Already thx in advance.

Comment: can you attempt to explain exactly what this script is supposed to do?  I don't know about you, but I find statements like `l_clean = sorted(zip(zip(*l)[1], zip(*l)[4],))` to be a little dense so it's a lot of work to try to unravel all of that to figure out what you're attempting ...

Comment: Yes,first you have to see that the AVB/DAS/BEDR are insurence types and that every adress has a insurence. This scripts looks for adresses when adresses are the same it generates the adress and combines the insurences behind it. I hope i informed you eneugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a difficult time understanding what you're trying to do, but perhaps this will help:

```
from itertools import groupby
import operator
#input
l = [['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'] ,
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'] ,
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'] ,
['Slever ', 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T. Slever']]
#script
sortkey = operator.itemgetter(1,4)
l_clean = sorted(l,key=sortkey)

l_final = [(k, list(v)) for k,v in groupby(l_clean, key = operator.itemgetter(1))]

for k,v in l_final:
   info_rest = v[0][:4]+v[0][5:]
   info_combine = map(operator.itemgetter(4),v) 
   print k,info_combine,info_rest
```

Basically, I sorted all of the data based on a specific key.  This way you don't lose any data during the sort stage. I then changed the key in `groupby` to be consistent with the new data layout and printed the results.

Comment: Now i get double entry's isn't there a possibity to just get this as output:                                                        Wei 9-11 ['AVB', 'BEDR']+other data 
klopt 42 ['AVB']+other data 
plein 92 ['AVB', 'BEDR']+other data 
tiellaan 42 ['AVB', 'DAS']+ other data                             Sorry for spamming but this i can't seem to get this problem fixed

Comment: @user1752643 Does my edit help?  To get your exact output, you could do `v[0][:4]+info_combine+v[0][5:]` I think ...